# How do I get yesterday's date in Fortran 90

Tags: gfortran

I have a FORTRAN 90 program where I have to use yesterday's date, say today is 19th, I want my program to use 18th. I am able to use date_and_time function to get today's date. But I am not able to get yesterday's date from this or from other Fortran date functions. My alternative is to get the date in Perl and write the date to a file which Fortran can read.
Below is my Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use strict;

use DateTime qw( );
my $yday_datetime =
DateTime
 ->now( time_zone => 'local' )
 ->subtract( days => 1 )
 ->strftime('%Y-%m-%d');
my($year, $month, $day) = split('-', $yday_datetime, 3);
my $ydate = $year . $month . $day;
print "$ydate\n";
```

Either I write `$ydate` into a file, then read it with Fortran (straight forward, or call this Perl script in Fortran (please assist how), or better still, get the date directly in Fortran.

Comment: The [Fortran DATE_AND_TIME subroutine](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/DATE_005fAND_005fTIME.html) returns 8 integer values that make up the date and time.  Value 3 is the day of the month.  Subtract 1 from value 3.

Comment: Thanks, that's one way of doing it, but if, e.g.  it is the first day of the month then a complication arises. One would need to test if the year is the same. So a length subroutine to test all possibilities.

Comment: Yep,  Check for 1/1 -> 12/31, X/1 -> (X-1)/28,29,30,31.  Maybe 15 lines of code.

Comment: It is beter to use libraries to manipulating dates. Like https://github.com/wavebitscientific/datetime-fortran Unless you know that you do not care about corner cases, year 0, years divisible by 400 and similar.

Comment: Thank you @"Vladimir F Героям слава". I have downloaded that library and I will take a look at it> However, here is what I have found to work after an afternoon of trying.         CALL execute_command_line('date -d "1 day ago" +"%Y%m%d", > tmp.txt')
        open(1,file='tmp.txt')
        read(1,'(a8)') yestaday
        print*,yestaday !Prints 20230518 Problem is resolved in 3 lines of Fortran code. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working solution

```
CALL execute_command_line('date -d "1 day ago" +"%Y%m%d", > tmp.txt')
open(1,file='tmp.txt')
read(1,'(a8)') yestaday
print*,yestaday !Prints 20230518 as of 20230519
```

Comment: I do not see any edit by Machavity. That code was written by me. Why is Machavity appearing here? There is nowhere where he has commented.

Comment: or is it from Machavity's post where I got CALL execute_command_line('date -d "1 day ago" +"%Y%m%d", > tmp.txt')?

Comment: If you look carefuly, you will see that it said that Machiavity edited your post. If you click on the "edited May 19" link, you will se what Machiavity did. Your previous answer wasn't really an answer. Now it is.